# A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: visual-studio

```
Private Sub DGV_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellEndEdit


    Try
        Dim i As Integer = DGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        Dim j As Integer = DGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex


        If j = 1 Then
            If DGV.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value <> Nothing Then
                Dim DT = New DataTable
                DT.Clear()
                DT = cls_account_.searsh_code(Val(DGV.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value))
                If DT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    DGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = DT.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
                    DGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DT.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
                Else
                    DGV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = Nothing
                    DGV.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe add some description to you problem?

Comment: Hi, Please add what your problem is and what you expect to happen. When you  run thet program do you get a NullReferenceException. From which line do you get a null reference exception ?